# How can I test Quill with jQuery events in jasmine?

Tags: jasmine, keydown, quill

For HTML inputs (notably, `textarea`), I can send a fake jQuery event to my input while testing in Jasmine and observe behavior that would occur in a browser if that same event were initiated by a user.

For example,

```
var $input = $('textarea');
var e = new jQuery.Event('keydown', { which: 13 });
$input.trigger(e);
```

This code would find my input and send a fake `enter` keydown during the test, and event handlers update the page in Jasmine. Then I can check values of elements on the page, or assess whether my spies have been called.

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work with Quill. I have verified that the input exists, that the input is focused, that my `onEnter` handler exists, etc. Yet, I have been struggling to figure out how to use a simulated/automated event to test this library.

Any help is greatly appreciated ^_^

Comment: Are you just wanting spies to work or do you want an actual newline to appear? I don't believe that latter works at all: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KvxZOy

Comment: I have used the Keyboard module's key bindings (https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/keyboard/) to set up some additional behavior inside my app, which has effects both inside and outside of the Quill container. However, when I send the fake event to `$('.ql-editor')`, it seems the handler I specified in the Keyboard module for the enter key is never called, as though it is not passing the fake event on to my key bindings.

I do not necessarily want a newline to appear, but I do want my custom handler to run.